# How to make FeatureSummary include packages found by pkg_check_modules

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project (foo)
include(FeatureSummary)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)
pkg_check_modules(JSON REQUIRED json-c)
feature_summary(WHAT ALL)
```

Running `cmake .` gives me:

```
-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * OpenSSL
```

Can anyone explain the trick to make `FeatureSummary` also include packages found by `pkg_check_modules`?

**UPDATE**

If I create a file named `FindJSON.cmake` with the following code:

```
find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)
# --> Still using pkg_check_modules
pkg_check_modules(JSON REQUIRED QUIET json-c)
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(
  JSON
  DEFAULT_MSG
  JSON_LIBRARIES
  JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
```

and change `CMakeLists.txt` to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project (foo)
include(FeatureSummary)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH . ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
# --> Now using find_package which still uses pkg_check_modules
find_package(JSON REQUIRED)
feature_summary(WHAT ALL)
```

I get:

```
-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * OpenSSL
 * JSON
```

That is fine. What has changed?

I use `find_package_handle_standard_args`. Alright let me just copy the content of `FindJSON.cmake` to `CMakeLists.txt`, instead of using it through `find_package`.

The new `CMakeLists.txt` will look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project (foo)
include(FeatureSummary)
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)
# --> The code from from FindJSON.cmake
find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)
# --> Still using pkg_check_modules
pkg_check_modules(JSON REQUIRED QUIET json-c)
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(
  JSON
  DEFAULT_MSG
  JSON_LIBRARIES
  JSON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
# <-- end of code from FindJSON.cmake
feature_summary(WHAT ALL)
```

and the output:

```
-- The following REQUIRED packages have been found:

 * OpenSSL
```

`JSON` has disappeared again.

So `find_package` does some magic of which I am unaware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* magic happening inside find_package.  It's storing the names of packages into global properties.

You can mess with those properties yourself:

```
set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY PACKAGES_FOUND MyJunkPackage)
```

Check the source of `FeatureSummary.cmake` to see which other properties and variables it refers to in order to produce.  For example, to make this package show up in the "required" list,

```
set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY _CMAKE_MyJunkPackage_TYPE REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_package_handle_standard_args` and pass the according variables from `find_package`.

```
pkg_check_modules(FOO)
find_package_handle_standard_args(FOO
  DEFAULT_MSG
  FOO_FOUND
  )
```

In your case replace `FOO` by `SQLITE3`.

Documentation:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.html

Alternatively, to add a custom entry to the feature summary use `add_feature_info`.

The documentation states:

> ```
> add_feature_info(<name> <enabled> <description>)
> ```
>
> Use this macro to add
>   information about a feature with the given `<name>`. `<enabled>` contains
>   whether this feature is enabled or not, `<description>` is a text
>   describing the feature.[..]
>
> Example for setting the info for a feature:
>
> ```
> option(WITH_FOO "Help for foo" ON)
> add_feature_info(Foo WITH_FOO "The Foo feature provides very cool stuff.")
> ```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FeatureSummary.html

Comment: If you look at `FindOpenSSL.cmake` there is no use of `option` or `add_feature_info`. I have used the method you describe for toggle features. This is not the same as far as I can see.

Comment: I think you are onto something there. I'll check later when I have the time.

Comment: It all happens inside `find_package` which I suspect is an internal method. I have briefly read through `FeatureSummary.cmake` for which variables it checks. I have come up empty handed so far.

Comment: see my update. Your updated question does not help, imho.

Comment: The update is meant to highlight that `find_package_handle_standard_args` is not enough to make anything act like `find_package` in my experiments.

Comment: I will try what you are suggesting. I could have made a mistake when I tried last time.